# Installing/upgrading GCC compilier for testing C++

Tags: 10.10, gcc, c++

I have ubuntu 10.10, and I have been learning c++ lately on it. I originally installed the gcc compilier via the command:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

I would like to start learning/testing the newer c++ features and I think it would be best to have the latest version of gcc installed. Im just needing some advice on this.

Is it possible to put a newer version of gcc in a separate folder that I can use for testing?

or

Is it possible/should I upgrade the current running version of gcc compilier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can download a newer version of gcc as a tarball and compile it with the current kernel installed. You can find gcc (and binutils) here:

[GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html)

> Is it possible/should I upgrade the current running version of gcc compilier

No you should not and cannot simply upgrade the compiler via the package management system. Further this could lead to dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, at least on Debian squeeze, and probably therefore on Ubuntu, which tends to be more recent than Debian, to backport Debian gcc packages.

See my answer on ask.debian.net to my own question, namely http://ask.debian.net/questions/backporting-more-recent-versions-of-the-gcc-toolchain-to-debian-stable.

More details available on request.